# How to open docusign home page auto logged in?

Tags: authentication, docusignapi

We are creating a windows based application on .Net 4.0 platform. There will be service representatives working on this application who will be creating documents online and sending it to the concerned persons. For all these representatives we will have a common username and password to login to DocuSign to upload and create the docusign document.

For this we want the representatives NOT to fill the username and password manually, but they will be auto logged-in when they try to open the docusign page in the browser on the click event of a button given in the windows application., which will say "Go To Docusign".

When the user clicks this "Go To Docusign" button on the win form application, browser window is opened and user is auto-logged-in as well.

Is their any mechanism that we genarate a token through REST based API of DocuSign and pass that in the Query String of the browser and our representative gets logged-in.

OR Suggest any other approach that will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use **Embedded Sending** authenticating as the one signer user that you share. This will restrict your users from knowing the account credentials as well.

[Embedded Sending - REST Documentation Here](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=27)

## **Embedded Sending**

The embedded sending resource retrieves a url for accessing the tagging and sending page of the 
DocuSign console. The envelope ID used here is the envelope that is opened in the console view. 
To open an envelope in the console for embedded sending, the 
`/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender` uri is appended to the base Url 
value to get the url to open the envelope in the DocuSign console. 
After opening the envelope in the console, you can make changes to the envelope and send it.

### *Example Request*

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/ 
{envelopeId}/views/sender 

X-DocuSign-Authentication: 
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials> 
Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 
{ 
 "returnUrl":"https://www.docusign.com" 
}
```

**Response**

The response returns the url to access the console.
 
The following example shows the header followed by the response json body.

### *Example Response*

```
201 Created 
Content-Length: 168 
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:53:16 GMT 

{"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/Member\/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=6cafaeaa-cc6b-
496d-812d-421b72f854de&DocuEnvelope=AB52A90E-BDC7-4F59-BFBD-90E32E984EA7&send=1"}
```